# Parse RDD into key-value pairs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data like the below in my csv file

Key-1, a1, 10, a2, 20, a3, 30

Key-2, b1, 50, b2, 60

Create an RDD and transform into another RDD where o/p should be like below

Key-1,a1

Key-1,a2

Key-1,a3

Key-2,b1

Key-2,b2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below code as per the above example.

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("path to the csv file") // here sc is sparkContext
val rdd1 = rdd.mapPartitions(itr => {
      itr.map(_.split(",")).map(_.toList).map(list => (list.head, list.tail))
 })
val rdd2 = rdd1.mapValues(tail => tail.zipWithIndex).map(tuple => (tuple._1, 
       tuple._2.filter(x => x._2 % 2 ==0).map(_._1)))
val rdd3 = rdd2.mapPartitions(itr => {
      itr.flatMap(xx => xx._2.map(k => (xx._1, k)))
})
rdd3.foreach(println)
(Key-2, b1)
(Key-2, b2)
(Key-1, a1)
(Key-1, a2)
(Key-1, a3)
```